# Running a function on an image created in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using [dataTables](http://datatables.net/) to retrieve, display and organise data from a PHP script (which in turn pulls the information from a MySQL database).

[image: My dataTables table]

Using the following code, dataTables retrieves the information and puts it into a.. well, table.

```
$('#content div').html( '<table id="example"></table>' );
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource": "dataTables.php",
    "aoColumns": [
        /* UID */           { "bSearchable": false,
                                "bVisible":  false },
        /* Datetime */      { "asSorting": [ "desc" ] },
        /* Staff Name */    null,
        /* Room */          null,
        /* Reason */        null,
        /* Urgency */       null,
        /* Processed? */    null ],
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        var sDirectionClass;

        if ( aData[6] === null ) {
            sDirectionClass = "new";
            if ( row % 2 !== 0 )
                sDirectionClass = "new_odd";
        } else {
            sDirectionClass = "std";
        }

        row++;

        $(nRow).addClass( sDirectionClass );
        return nRow;
    }
} );
```

Most of this, I hope, is quite straightforward - this function takes the `sAjaxSource` property and looks at my `dataTables.php` file, which simply reads the MySQL DB and returns some information in a JSON-encoded format.

This all works fine, but I'm trying to turn one of my table's columns into a clickable link.

The brief PHP for this is;

```
if ( $aColumns[$i] == "Processed" )
{
    $link = '<img src="tick.png" id="' . $aRow[ $aColumns[0] ] . '" />';
    $row[] = ( empty( $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ] ) ) ? $link : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
}
```

The pseudo for that is basically `if Processed field is NULL display an image with the UID of that row; otherwise display the value of Processed field`.

[image: Check or date]

What I'd like to do now is make that image JS-clickable to run an AJAX function. I thought that the following code (in situ immediately after the above JS):

```
oTable.find('img').click(function(){
    var process = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "check_alerts.php",
        data: { process: id }
    }).done(function() { 
        oTable.fnDraw(false);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, it appears to do nothing. I'd imagine this is because the `img` I'm creating is created in the DOM and as such when the above function runs, it won't find any `img` tags.

How can I amend the code so that those images will run my AJAX function?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that your new DOM elements also listen to the click event you should use "on".

```
oTable.on("click", "img", function() {
  var process = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: "check_alerts.php",
    data: { process: id }
  }).done(function() { 
    oTable.fnDraw(false);
  });
});
```

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: delegate is deprecated in favor of on()

Comment: `oTable.on("click", "img", function() {` was what I actually used, but thanks Michiel.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I'll update the answer (and my jquery version ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [jquery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which is specifically meant to bind events on dynamic content.

Try this:

```
//replace table with the table pointer (class,id)
$('table').on('img','click',function(){
   //do your thing
});
```

Comment: I've just given that a go, but nothing seems to happen. Could you offer some example code?

Comment: Ah, silly me - my version of jQuery was outdated. `on` worked, but I'll be giving the answer to Michiel as his answer was more full. +1 though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using firebug to see if the image tag is generated. 
Than try running your image click binding function in firebug console tab. If that works than probably you are trying to bind the click event too soon in your original page execution cycle.